# how to use a 3rd security option in symfony2 secured login

Tags: symfony-2.0

I am using **symfony2.0 secured login** for my login page.

I have a column name **blockstatus** in my login table which contains value **1 (blocked user)** or **0 (active user)**.

I need to check username, password and **also blockstatus column (0 means allow to login)** while login.

I think I need to do some changes in **security.yml**. I googled about it no idea. I am new to Symfony.

Comment: Please m8, don't put 'thanks' and 'please' in your questions. Just explain your problem and that's enough.

Comment: i would go for the loginSuccessHandler listener which allow you to add some logic to the login (see : http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/)